# Magento2: What are the differences on API Enterprise?

Tags: magento2, api, magento2-enterprise

What are the exclusive features that are provided on Magento 2 Enterprise edition API comparing with the Community edition?

Answer (score 0):

The exclusive features on Magento 2 Enterprise Edition are:

**1. CustomerBalance**

**2. GiftCardAccount**

**3. GiftRegistry**

**4. GiftWrapping**

**5. Reward**

**6. Rma**

You can find more details and how you can use in this DevDocs page:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/rest/list.html